# Android Studio: What is the shortcut of "Quick Assist"

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm newbie on Android Studio. I want to know that is there any quick assist exist in Android Studio ?

For example, CTRL+2,F combination is assigning to field in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

To extract field  CTRL+ALT+F

To extract variable CTRL+ALT+V